# How to split the list on the pairwise elements?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Let us have a list, there is always an even number of elements. We must break it down by pairing.
Example:
list['1','2','3','4']
need
1,2 and 3,4

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> pairs = zip(L[::2], L[1::2])
>>> print pairs
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want two halfs of a list.

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
print l[:len(l)/2], l[len(l)/2:]
>>> [1, 2] [3, 4]
```

If you want split a list by pairs then your question is exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python).

Comment: and if have more elements [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] ? =))

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this too:

```
lVals = xrange(1,101)
size = len(lVals)
output = ((lVals[i], lVals[i+1] if size > i+1 else None) for i in xrange(0, size, 2))
```

Comment: I don't think this one works, try it out!

Comment: @juanchopanza i have tried is several times and it works for me - if use 'res = list(output)' you will get a list of tuples for example:  res[2] == (3,4)

Comment: It gives (1,2),(2,3),(3,4) and so on, instead of (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) are required. You need output = ((lVals[i], lVals[i+1] if size > i+1 else None) for i in xrange(0,size,2))

Comment: @juanchopanza - yes, you right, my fault. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312644#312644)

```
from itertools import izip_longest
data = range(6)
data_iters = [iter(data)] * 2
pairs = izip_longest(*data_iters)
[pair for pair in pairs]
>>> [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

The clever part is that the two elements of data_iters refer to the same object. Izip_longest alternately consumes from the two iterators passed as arguments, but since they're referring to the same object, it effectively pairs the elements in the iterator.

I take no credit for being clever here, upvote the comment I linked to if you liked my answer. :)